# FFMPEG under Windows 7(64 bit) - creating timelaps video from jpg

Tags: windows-7, video, ffmpeg, jpeg, timelapse

My goal is to create a video from a bunch of jpg files. I have chosen FFMPEG (Windows 64) to solve this task

**The task**

I have more than 4k jpg files in a directory, all following the naming convention `pic_000000X.jpg` (where `x` is a number)
i.e. `pic_0000001.jpg`,`pic_0000002.jpg`,.,`pic_0001337.jpg` and so on which I want to create a timelaps video from.

**Result**

When I run `ffmpeg -i pic_%7d.jpg -s:v 1280x720 -c:v libx264 output.mp4` I get the `output.mp4` file but it is small and contains only few pictures/frames - nine to be precise (running the reverse command `ffmpeg -i output.mp4 test%d.jpg` I get `test1.jpg` to `test9.jpg`)

**Observation**

It seems to work until `pic_0000009.jpg` and then the pattern does not recognize `pic_00000010.jpg` onwards.

What am I missing or am I doing wrong to only include nine pictures?
Thanks for time and effort for giving me some hints.

Cheers.

P.S. I tried the `blob` style file pattern but it does not work under windows

P.P.S. If you know of another tool that lets me achieve the task let me know as well

Comment: Try replace with `pic%7d.jpg` with `pic_%7d.jpg` (note the `_`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My mistake - it is a typo in the description. Will change it.

Comment: Also `00000010` is 8 digits. `0000001` is 7 digits. You need to add an extra `0` to the first 9 files? Check all file have the same number of digits and use that number in the expression.

Comment: You could also try `'pic_%*.jpg'`(note the `'`s)

Comment: I found my error - it were the digits. My python script did not take into consideration the # of digits when creating the files.
Thanks for your help to resolve this. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I messed up the file format for my input files, ending up with files that had 7digits and more. Now that all files correspond to the same file name pattern everything works as expected.
Cheers.